# Running CSS animation from jQuery synchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

Is there any way to wait until CSS DOM changes applied?

Here is an example:

CSS:

```
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.anim {
    transition: transform 2s;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".box").css("transform", "translate3d(200px,0,0)");
$(".box").addClass("anim");
$(".box").css("transform", "translate3d(210px,0,0)");
```

JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tfxbej9q/

**What I expected**: `<div>` jumps to position 200, then animation is enabled and browser smoothly moves `<div>` 10px to right (position 210).

**What happens**: `<div>` is smoothly moved from position 0 to 210.

My solution (but I don't like it): Add `setTimeout` function:

```
 $(".box").css("transform", "translate3d(200px,0,0)");
 setTimeout(function() {
      $(".box").addClass("anim");
      $(".box").css("transform", "translate3d(210px,0,0)");
 }, 10);
```

Is there any functions waiting until DOM changes applied?

Comment: This isn't jQuery animation. If you want to use that library they have an easy to use animate() method. http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue a couple of weeks ago, and used window.requestAnimationFrame to solve it.

This is not really a jQuery issue, this is the browser trying to save on repaints. and the only way to fix it is to force the browser to use 2 repaints either by using a timeout/requestAnimationFrame/.delay(1) or by forcing a recalculation of the styles with something like offsetHeight.

```
$(".box").css("transform", "translate3d(200px,0,0)");
window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
  $(".box").addClass("anim");
  $(".box").css("transform", "translate3d(210px,0,0)");
});
```

it looks a lot like your solution with the timeout.
[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/0ygohj6b/)

```
$(".box").css("transform", "translate3d(200px,0,0)");
$(".box").get(0).offsetHeight;
$(".box").addClass("anim");
$(".box").css("transform", "translate3d(210px,0,0)");
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ok9z73w3/)

mgHenry made a small extension to jQuery to make this look a bit nicer in your code https://gist.github.com/mgHenry/6154611

Answer (score -1):

You could use jquery functions/methods that have a `complete` callback option, such as [jquery animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/).